# Sliding Window Protocol with ACK

Tags: networking

I'm working on this problem and sort of stuck on one part.  To set it up I basically have two nodes Node 1 and Node 2 that use sliding window protocol with 3 bit sequence.  Go-back-n ARQ is used with window size of 4.  Node 1 is sender, Node 2 is receiver.

If Node 1 sends frame 0, 1, 2 and Node 2 receives them and sends back ACK 1 to Node 1 and Node 1 receives the ACK.

This means that Node 2 only received frame 0 only?

So Node 1 would look like this?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/erVJE.png

And Node 2 would look like this?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbtpf.png

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am dealing a question something like this. @Nick